# UWP - replace StackPanel to make inner content stretchable inside GridView

Tags: xaml, uwp-xaml

I have problems to stretch my table (GridView with StackPanel inside) to make the UI responsive for Desktop and Mobile Apps. It looks like a StackPanel is only fitting the size of its inner elements. Is there an element that can replace my StackPanel but is stretchable?

```
<GridView ItemsSource="{x:Bind Stuff}" IsHitTestVisible="True"
                  IsItemClickEnabled="False"
                  IsSwipeEnabled="False" Margin="0,90,0,0" x:Name="myGridView" ShowsScrollingPlaceholders="False" SelectionMode="None" IsTapEnabled="False" IsRightTapEnabled="False" IsHoldingEnabled="False" IsDoubleTapEnabled="False" ManipulationMode="None" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="360"><GridView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemsPanel>
            <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:StuffVM">
                    <Grid Tag="{Binding Url}" Tapped="Grid_Tapped">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="7*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Padding="5,5,5,5" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Date}" FontSize="12" Foreground="#FFFFE680" Width="Auto"/>
                        <TextBlock Padding="5,5,5,5" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Text}" FontSize="12" Foreground="#FFFFE680" Width="Auto"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemTemplate>
        </GridView>
```

Answer (score -1):

Is there a reason that you are using a StackPanel as the ItemsPanelTemplate? ItemsWrapGrid or ItemsStackPanel should stretch and use the available area.